# Java Partial Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have a few classes linked to each other

```
public class A implements java.io.Serializable{
    public B objB;
}

public class B {//doesn't implement serializable
}
```

When I try to serialize A, I get error because B is not serializable
What I want to do is to serialize A and load B again after de-serializing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a7231) for ignore objB during serialization:

> The easiest technique is to mark fields that contain sensitive data as
>   private transient. Transient fields are not persistent and will not be
>   saved by any persistence mechanism.

```
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {
    public transient B objB;
}
```